# Capture exception in for statement

Tags: python, exception, iterator

I would like to capture an exception thrown by an intetartor in one of its iterations outside the loop of the iterator.

This is a very simplified version of the code:

```
class C(object):
    def _iter(self):
        for x in range(100):
            yield x, x + 3

    def doit(self):
        for a, b in self._iter():    # <-- how can I capture an excepcion here?
            print(a, b)
```

I could capture the exception in the iterator loop but then I how can I pass the error to the `doit` method for reporting? I would like to let the exception propagate all the way to the `doit` function where I can just collect the errors and continue with the next element.

Also I need to process all the iterations, collect the errors and process all the iterations without erros so I can report all the errors at the end. That way, a single error would not prevent the processing of all the other elements.

Comment: Why not deal with the error *inside* the `_iter()` instance method?

Comment: @F.C. Do you want to continue the loop `for a, b in self._iter(): ` after you catched and processed an error? Am I the only one interpreting it like this?

Comment: @jonrsharpe because inside `_iter` I can't collect all the errors, and because `_iter` must return something `doit` can use.

Comment: @Nabla that is the issue, I want to collect all the errors and process all the iterations without erros and report the errors at the end.

Comment: @Nabla thank you, mark as duplicate if you like

Answer (score 0):

Use a try-catch block.

```
try:
  for a, b in self._iter():
    print(a, b)

except:
  #throw your exception text here
```

Comment: This is not what OP asked for: `where I can just collect the errors and continue with the next element`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
class C(object):
    def _iter(self):
      try:  
          for x in range(100):
            yield x, x + 3
      except Exception as e:
          raise e

    def doit(self):
        try:
            for a, b in self._iter():    # <-- how can I capture an excepcion here?
                print(a, b)
        except Exception as e:
            # do something with e
        # rest of the python code here
```

Comment: This will end the generator if an Exception occurs, while OP wants to continue it.